# SPARQL Query Involving Chinese Characters

Tags: sparql

I am running the following query to obtain translations for the English word "father" on [this](http://kaiko.getalp.org/sparql) public endpoint:

```
PREFIX dbnary: <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#>
select distinct ?l ?written where
{
dbnary-eng:father dbnary:describes ?le .
?t dbnary:isTranslationOf ?le .
?t dbnary:targetLanguage ?l .
?t dbnary:writtenForm ?written .
}
```

Among the strings returned, I can also find the Chinese translation "爸爸".
When I try to reverse the query, I do not receive any result for Chinese words (it works for other languages):

```
PREFIX dbnary: <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#>
select distinct ?c where
{
?c dbnary:describes ?le .
?t dbnary:isTranslationOf ?le .
?t dbnary:targetLanguage ?l .
?t dbnary:writtenForm "爸爸" .
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"爸爸"@yue` or `"爸爸"@cmn`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, your answer is correct (feel free to add it as official answer). 
However, I wonder why I need those language annotations. The first query does not indicate that those are required (only some Strings have language annotations there - but not the Chinese ones). Do you know the answer to this as well?

Comment: *"The first query does not indicate that those are required*" — select e.g. the "JSON" option in the "Results Format" list, or add something like `bind(lang(?written) as ?lang` to your first query. Web UI just skips language tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Stanislav Kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin) correctly points out, the reason for the query not working is the missing language annotation. The correct query formulation is as follows:

```
PREFIX dbnary: <http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#>
select distinct ?c where
{
   ?c dbnary:describes ?le .
   ?t dbnary:isTranslationOf ?le .
   ?t dbnary:targetLanguage ?l .
   {?t dbnary:writtenForm "爸爸"@yue .}
   UNION {?t dbnary:writtenForm "爸爸"@cmn .}
}
```